# Set the flag on getting the Data from @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
@Input() config= [];
flag = false;
```

I have to set my flag true only on the condition when I get the data in the config from the @input which is the best place to do that?
There is delay in getting the data in the config which i am not getting on the ngOnInit but getting on ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 4):

One straight-forward way to do it without even utilizing anything Angular is to use a setter. It basically gives you a way to intercept *setting* of a property, where you can set your `flag` to true.

```
private _config

@Input() set config (config) {
  this._config = config
  this.flag = true
}

get config () {
  return this._config
}
```